# Print not working without parenthesis (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, compiler-errors, syntax-error

When I run below code, I get "Syntax Error: invalid syntax". However, if I run this code with parentheses after print, I get the correct answer.

```
liczby = [
951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
743, 527]
for x in liczby:
    if x == 237:
        break
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print x
```

I would like to add, that this is not the only thing I ran in this notebook, I have (among other) included some packages:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import tarfile
from IPython.display import display, Image
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
```

At the end, I would like to add, that in a new workbook everything works correctly. Does anybody have an idea, what can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is causing the problem: `from __future__ import print_function`.

This means that you are importing the **new print_function** from **Python 3** into **Python 2.7**. Hence, parenthesis are required. More on [future imports](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be able to print without parentheses since you're importing the print statement from python 3 `from __future__ import print_function`
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print